# Is it possible to enable SeDebugPrivilege on another process

Tags: c#, debugging, process

In C# is it possible to enable SeDebugPrivilege on another process similarly to how Procees.EnterDebugMode works for the current process and if so are there any examples available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use `OpenProcessToken` to open the process token, , being sure to specify `TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY`.
This will give you a token handle.

Then use `AdjustTokenPrivileges` to adjust the privileges of the token.

The function `OpenProcessToken` requires a process handle. If you only have the process ID, you can obtain the required handle using the `OpenProcess` function.